# Удаление файла в Android

Tags: android, файлы

В приложении отображается некоторый список файлов. Но соль в том что эти файлы могут быть удалены пользователем из файловой системы через проводник(ну или из какой нить другой програмы). Так как во время исполнения программы отловить событие удаления файла и благополучно извлечь его из списка???? Если можно пожалуйста ссылки на информацию или библиотеки) Заранее благодарен)

Comment: Для того, чтобы удалить, юзер должен запустить другое приложение. Соответственно Ваше будет свёрнуто или закрыто. Ну а после запуска или разворачивания Вы либо формируете список снова, либо можете его перепроверить.

Comment: @woesss в теории фоновый сервис может удалить файл

Comment: Тогда нужен [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) . Небольшой примерчик на en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18592392

Comment: @ woesss Спасибо за пример) А если файл открыт в даный момент времени?